# Expected identifier or '('

Tags: c, header-files

I want to write a program to compute the `k` power of `n`, by defining a function called `power(k)`. Then I want to use it in another file under the same project to output a table of 3^k, where the range of `k` is 0-9. But I got a error when I tried to compile my codes.

I will appreciate you if you could point out my mistake.

```
//  main.c
//  #9-product of n
//
//  Created by Leslie on 11/13/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Jiahui. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
int n;
long product;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long power(int k);
    int k;
    printf("Please input the number n and k\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
    product=power(k);
    printf("the product is %ld\n",product);
}

long power(int k)
{
    product=1;
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        product=product*n;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Second program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.c"
extern long power(int k);

for(i=1;i<=9;i++)
{
    printf("%d\t",power(k));
}
```

Comment: Please post the code here

Comment: Code as image? Place it as a formatted text here, please.

Comment: Why did you declare prototype inside `main`  ?

Comment: move the power function before the main function then you don't have to predeclare it.

Comment: it this THAT homework again...

Comment: You could save some time and use the [pow function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Comment: Why do you include the `xcode` tag?  Your issue is with the code, not the IDE or platform.

Comment: Your second program will not compile as it is **not valid C**. The code appears on its own, not inside a function. In addition, you should not have a `main` in a *functions-only* file to be included elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite see the point of another file under the same project just to print powers of three, but that's possibly your homework.

Anyway, I think the whole point is to see how to include a file, so I also isolated the power function in another file.

power_calculator.c will accept two parameters, {number} and {power} respectively.

Here is how you can do it:

power_calculator.c

```c
// power_calculator {n} {k}
// Calculates {n}^{k}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// #include <math.h>
#include "math_power.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // two parameters should be passed, n, and k respectively - argv[0] is the name of the program, and the following are params.
    if(argc < 3)
        return -1;
    // you should prefer using math.h's pow function - in that case, uncomment the #import <math.h>
    //printf("%f\n", power(atof(argv[1]), atof(argv[2])));

    // atof is used to convert the char* input to double
    printf("%f\n", math_power(atof(argv[1]), atof(argv[2])));

    return 0;
};
```

math_power.h

```c
#ifndef _MATH_POWER_H_
#define _MATH_POWER_H_

double math_power(double number, double power);

#endif
```

math_power.c

```c
#include "math_power.h"

double math_power(double number, double power){
    double result = 1;
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < power; i++ ){
        result*=number;
    }

    return result;
}
```

powers_of_three.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math_power.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    // here is your range 0-9
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%f\n", math_power(3, i));

    return 0;
};
```

To compile either powers_of_three.c or power_calculator.c, remember to include math_power.h and math_power.c.